# Decompress gzip data without header using Node.JS zlib module

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

I have a binary data which is a GZIP compressed string. Both header and footer are absent, but the string is otherwise correct. I verified this by using Node.js `zlib.gzip()` to compress the same string and then comparing the two binary files.

Is it possible to use `zlib` library to uncompress files without header and footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`zlib.inflateRaw()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_inflateraw_buffer_options_callback) and friends.